# DBT fails with not found in location when using a seed

Tags: dbt

I'm trying to build a dbt project with seed. Something very similar to [this](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/seeds/).

To create a temporary table, I use `dbt seed` and reference the table as given in the example in the link above.

I do some post processing of the raw csv file in `data/` and call that `sql` file as `processed_seed_file.sql` in `models/`.

However, when I referencing it in a macro as part of another sql file in `models/`,
it fails with the following error `processed_seed_file was not found in location EU`

the macro looks as follows

```
-- depends_on: {{ ref('processed_seed_file') }}

{{-
      config(
        materialized = 'ephemeral',
        verbose=True
    )
-}}

{%- call statement('start_statement', fetch_result=True) -%}
        SELECT DATE_SUB(MIN(start), INTERVAL CAST('{{ var("some_var") }}' as INT64) WEEK)
        FROM {{ ref('processed_seed_file') }}
{%- endcall -%}
{%- set start_date = load_result('start_statement')['data'][0][0] -%}
```

Any hints on where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure it's not the most obvious thing, have you run `dbt run`?

Comment: I did, but haven't found a decent way to fix it. i found another way to fix it by not using macros. I uploaded the csv file in the database and it worked.

Comment: That's odd. So, you created the .csv file in the `data/` directory, ran `dbt seed`, created the .sql file in the `models/` directory that references the seed file name like `{{ ref('seed_file_name') }}`, ran `dbt run` and still got that error? How were you running the macro?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had it happen to me recently on dbt 1.5

The apparent cause is running a Docker container (or similar), which changes the owner of the seed files. To fix it I had to `chown` the files back to the developer user, and then `dbt clean && dbt deps && dbt parse` to allow dbt to see the files again.